# Debian Network Configuration

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, debian-jessie

I have a Debian VPS on which I am trying to open some ports like 80, 443, etc. and here's what I've done:

Creating a test iptables file:

```
 editor /etc/iptables.test.rules
```

which has some basic rules:

```
*filter
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
COMMIT
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error on all lines:

```
iptables-restore: line xx failed
```

and I need to enable these ports ASAP so what's wrong?

update: fixed everything but now I can't connect to the server via any form (put the address in a browser's address bar and go to it)

P.S.: I'm using this server for my home automation project as a mid point (An Android app issues the commands to the server which in turn issues it to the raspberry pi which controls the house and then the pi sends back a response of success or failure) - on which I'm trying to do the following:

1- enable some ports like 80 & 443 which I have enabled using iptables but still can't put the server's address in a browser's address bar and navigate to it.

2- how will the app communicate with the server noting that sign up & login will take place through the server as I'm right now have both the app & the Pi ready but separate (not connected together & I already know that they will communicate over HTTP but what I don't know is how ?)

Comment: `line xx failed` so which line is `xx`.  That error usually is a number.  That number tells you the line with the failure.  If you gave us the actual error message, it would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @Zoredache all the lines

Comment: Typically use a shell script so each line starts with the path to the iptables executable... `/usr/bin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -dport 80 -j ACCEPT` .  Alternatively if you simply want to allow/disallow to ports use UFW and its super simple syntax of `ufw allow ssh` or `ufw allow 80` etc

Comment: @ivanivan I used `ufw allow ssh` and still nothing happened